# Hostname changes history in unix systems

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, hostname

I've been trying to find a command or file that contains all the previous hostnames a Linux/Solaris machine has had, but I can't seem to find any way to do this.

The question is really about the command or file that would contain such information, in large system audits of unknown servers and outdated reportings that would be quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

There is no file that contains this history. *Perhaps* you may be able to pull it out of syslog, but you're going to have to go searching for it.